# Default Attributes in EJB Transactions

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I ma reading the [java ee docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html) and I would like to ask a couple of question to be sure I have understood well what is going on with EJB-Transactions.

1) The docs state that the defaalt `TransactionManagement` value is `CONTAINER`  and the the default `TransactionAttribute` value is `REQUIRED`: If so, am I right that the following (Session) Bean executes all its methods in with `CONTAINER` managed Transactions and the attribute `REQUIRED`?

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean{

public void methodA(){
...
}

public void methodB(){
...
}

}
```

2) The docs state: `Container-managed transactions do not require all methods to be associated with transactions. When developing a bean, you can set the transaction attributes to specify which of the bean’s methods are associated with transactions.`

If I omit however the `TransactionAttributeType`, is it not automatically set to `REQUIRED`? Is the `methodB` in the following Bean not associated with a Transaction?

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(CONTAINER)
public class MyBean{

@TransactionAttribute(MANDATORY)
public void methodA(){
...
}

public void methodB(){
...
}

}
```

Answer (score 11):

1. Yes, `CONTAINER` and `REQUIRED` are the default.
2. The quote you gave seems to come from [The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html). I agree that sentence is somewhat confusingly worded. Here's a possible rewriting that might help.

> Container-managed transactions do not require all methods to use the
>   default REQUIRED transaction semantics. When developing a bean, you
>   can change the transaction semantics by setting the transaction
>   attributes. For example, you can specify that a method should run
>   without any transaction by using the NEVER transaction attribute,

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. By default method has transaction settings REQUIRED. Therefore methodB() has REQUIRED

Answer (score 0):

1- Yes.

2- methodB() has REQUIRED attribute as it`s the default attribute, but you can override this default attribute with any other options like (NEVER, REQUIRED_NEW, SUPPORTED... etc).

However, the container still has the control to roll-back your transaction in case of system exception but you still have the ability to roll-back your transactions by invoking the setRollbackOnly method.

> There are two ways to roll back a container-managed transaction. First, if a system exception is thrown, the container will automatically roll back the transaction. Second, by invoking the setRollbackOnly method of the EJBContext interface, the bean method instructs the container to roll back the transaction. If the bean throws an application exception, the rollback is not automatic but can be initiated by a call to setRollbackOnly.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnciv/index.html

Comment: So, if my class has @ stateless there's no need to add @ TransactionManagement because it's set by default. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Once you defined a class as an EJB using (@Statless or @Stateful) any transactions needed inside any one of its methods will be managed by container unless you change it.